# Modernization of physical file

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Please advise here..
I have a physical file (phy0001) and dependent logical (Log0001) & view (view0001). Wanted to add some extra fields on PHY0001 and decided to create new SQL table (Tab0001 )instead.
New TB0001 will have all fields of PHY0001 and some additional filed.
now PHY0001 and LOG0001 will point to TAB0001 as LF (using PFILE and FORMAT keyword, i am changing it and no impact to the existing process since format level identifier not changing)
here i am good so far PHY0001 and LOG0001 having no trouble and i don't need to re-compile the programs.
The issue is the view VIEW0001 (select * from PHY00001), i have assigning new table with selected filed as PHY0001 has (select "list of fields as phy0001" from TAB0001) and Format level identifier changed..
Please let me know if you know how can i retain same Format level identifier in view as well so i don't need to compile programs which is using VIEW0001.

Thank you

Comment: Does new new VIEW0001 have a different record format?  Can't you leave VIEW0001 as it is referencing PHY0001, might have to refresh it?

Comment: It has same record format but now PHY0001 became LF.. Now sure if i can have view on top of LF... that's why i am pointing view to new Tab0001

Comment: Logical file PHY0001 in LIBRARY not valid for CREATE VIEW. 
CREATE VIEW VIEW0001  AS (                    
  SELECT *                                   
  FROM PHY0001)

Comment: Have you looked to make sure your list of fields is the same and in the same order as the fields in the old VIEW0001?